# How to delete and add new contents in html file by python

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, highcharts

I am creating an HTML file which downloads its contents from highcharts.com. The head of the default HTML contents looks like below

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="https://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
```

I want to replace this with :

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="https://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
            <div id="container"></div>
            <p class="highcharts-description">
                Basic line chart showing trends in a dataset. This chart includes the
                <code>series-label</code> module, which adds a label to each line for
                enhanced readability.
            </p>
        </figure>

    </head>
```

I am using below code to write the default contents in HTML from highcharts.com (H)

```
# write out the html
FileName1 = "Highcharts_Test.html"
with open(FileName1, "wt") as fh:
    fh.write(H.htmlcontent)
```

How I can achieve the above?

Comment: if you have it as string then you can use standard string functions like `text_html.replace("</head>", "some_text </head>")`

Comment: it doesn't work. the lines are too long.  text_html.replace is part of python library or I need to import Html?

Comment: it is standard function `"Hello World".replace("Hello", "Goodbye")` And you can use variable with text `"Hello World".replace(variable1, variable2)` so you can assign multiline text using triple `"` - `variable = """here text in many lines"""` or you can read this text from file `variable = open(..).read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard `replace()` to replace `"</html>"` with `"some text </html>"`

```
html = '''<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="https://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/6/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>'''

new = '''
        <figure class="highcharts-figure">
            <div id="container"></div>
            <p class="highcharts-description">
                Basic line chart showing trends in a dataset. This chart includes the
                <code>series-label</code> module, which adds a label to each line for
                enhanced readability.
            </p>
        </figure>

</head>'''


html = html.replace('</head>', new)

print(html)
```